# как сделать позициониривание элементов

Tags: css, bootstrap, позиционирование

[image: имеется]

[image: как нужно сделать]

код:

```css
.elem {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 2px;
}

.id_name {
  width: 80%;
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
}

.id_sale {
  /*width: 80%;*/
  position: absolute;
  left: 80%;
  float: left;
}

.id_rate {
  display: inline-block;
  /*width: 80%;*/
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  float: left;
}

.id_in {
  /*width: 20%;*/
  position: absolute;
  top: 37%;
  left: 70%;
  float: left;
}


/*.id_img{
     display: inline-block;
     top: 100px;
     
    }*/

.id_price {
  position: absolute;
  top: 170px;
  font: 29px bold myFont;
  color: #039;
  float: left;
}

.id_add {
  position: absolute;
  left: 80%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="elem">
  <div class="id_name">Холодильник с нижней морозильной камерой Samsung E01A8</div>
  <div class="id_sale"><img src="sale.png" alt="sale"></div>
  <div class="id_rate"><img src="stars.png" class="img-responsive" alt="rate"></div>
  <div class="id_in">в наличии</div>
  <div class="id_img"><img src="01.png" class="img-responsive" alt="samsung_e01a8"></div>
  <div class="id_price">1999 p.</div>
  <div class="id_add"><img src="cart.png" class="img-responsive" alt="cart">забрать сегодня</div>
</div>
```

Comment: у вас тут бутстрап в виде `img-resposive` ?

Comment: для двух изображений - пылесоса и корзины - да.

Comment: если убрать этот класс - ничего не изменится.